# Connecting snowflake behind Okta and running in Airflow. Error: Enter the URL the SSO URL redirected you to:

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, single-sign-on, okta

We recently put Snowflake behind Okta so this is the first time I'm trying to get the Snowflake connection working locally in Airflow.

This is the code, I've only changed by adding the authenticator param, but I'm missing something, please see below for the logs as well:

```
from snowflake import connector as sfconn

conn = sfconn.connect(
            user=self.username,
            password=self.password,
            account=self.account,
            database=self.database,
            region=self.region,
            role=self.role_name,
            autocommit=self.autocommit,
            authenticator='externalbrowser'
        )
```

I see the following in the airflow logs:

> {logging_mixin.py:120} INFO - We were unable to open a browser window for you, please open the following url manually then paste the URL you are redirected to into the terminal.
>
> {logging_mixin.py:120} INFO - URL: https://login.xxx.com/app/snowflake/xxxxx/sso/saml?SAMLRequest=blahblah
>
> {logging_mixin.py:120} INFO - Enter the URL the SSO URL redirected you
> to:
>
> {taskinstance.py:1851} ERROR - Task failed with exception Traceback
> (most recent call last):
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake/connector/auth_webbrowser.py", line 139, in authenticate
>
> url = input("Enter the URL the SSO URL redirected you to: ")
>
> EOFError: EOF when reading a line

when I go to the URL provided in the logs, I see `Redirecting to Snowflake` then I see can't connect

I've tried this as well but didn't work:
https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/External-browser-SSO-from-connector-fails-on-redirect-back-to-localhost

Comment: It’s not normally good practice to have a connection between two systems that uses an identity provider, instead use a “service account” I.e. a Snowflake user with a fixed password that follows good security practises such as regularly changing the password

Comment: If you are using Native Okta and have no access to a browser, user as `authenticator='https://<okta_account_name>.okta.com'` as described [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-security-fed-auth-use#native-sso-okta-only)

Comment: @Sergiu - when I tried that I see: None: Failed to connect to DB: <account><region>.snowflakecomputing.com:443, The specified authenticator is not accepted by your Snowflake account configuration.  Please contact your local system administrator to get the correct URL to use. I'm trying w. the externalbrowser so that it would pop up the okta login window but its not working